# How to embed plots into a tab in RMarkdown in a procedural fashion?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I can embed plots using just RMarkdown's `{.tabset}`

````
#### Heading  {.tabset}
##### Subheading 1
```{r, echo=F}
df[[1]]    
```
````

This produces individual tabs with the specified graphs (`df` is a list of graphs, calling `df[[i]]` produces a graph) in the preview pane (renders all the graphs inline in RStudio).

---

And I can generate just the tabs using a for loop.

````
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
for (i in 1:length(gg0)) {
  cat("##### ",q$Subheading[i],"\n")
}
```
````

And this produces the desired output - the tabs with the names in the Subheading column.

---

However, I am stuck in trying to generate the graphs themselves using the for loop similar to how I did when I coded it manually.

Extending the above, I tried to generate the markdown that produced the initial output but the plot fails to generate (both in the inline markdown and preview).

````
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
for (i in 1:length(gg0)) {
  cat("##### ",q$Subheading[i],"\n")
    cat('```{r, echo=F} \n')
    cat("gg0[[",i,"]]\n")
    cat('``` \n')
}
```
````

Maybe I am missing a finer point regarding markdown? I have tried various patterns using `cat` (and even without)

I would prefer a RMarkdown solution but other solutions are just as welcome.

Comment: Could you provide a little dummy reproducible example? for example you talk about `df[[1]]` first and in your code u use `gg0[[i]]`.

Comment: I just made a copy of the original variable `df` as `gg0` just in case I overwrote it. But they are essentially the same data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I played around a little and found a solution. You have to use `print` within the `asis` code chunk...

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
gg0 <- list()
gg0[[1]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point()
gg0[[2]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
gg0[[3]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, drat)) + geom_point()

headings <- c('hp','disp','drat')
```

#### Heading  {.tabset}
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
for (i in 1:length(gg0)) {
  cat("##### ",headings[i],"\n")
  print(gg0[[i]])
  cat('\n\n')
}
```
````

As an explanation, the `cat` command together with `results='asis'` produces the markdown code for a lower level headline and prints the ggplot graph afterwards. Since we used `{.tabset} in the parent headline, it creates the plots in separate tabs.

Comment: I can plot them now! But they are all being printed in the last tab.

Comment: UPDATE: In addition, I have tried to generate another R code block inside the code block but the backticks keep being parsed as code formatting blocks. I'm looking for a way to anchor the graphic in that position after the subheading.

Comment: For me my example works with one fig per tab. I guess the chunk creation within a asisblock will not be parsed and will not work.

Comment: very useful. Could you explain what   cat("#####","Tab","\n") does? How are the plots being associated with each tab?

Comment: @ashleych added a short explanation.

Comment: @drmariod what is also weird is that only a double \n\n would work but not single.

Answer (score 2):

Adding both plot.new(), dev.off() inside the for loop solves the problem of adding all the figures in the last tab. See the complete solution [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1795#issuecomment-505779701).

Comment: the solution  doesnt work for me : I get a plot in the first tab,but not in the other 5