# Dynamically control number of tabsets in R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I want to be able to generate tabsets in my R markdown file based on a changing number of categories. I have written the following example .Rmd:

````
---
title: "Dynamic Tabsets"
output: html_document
---

# Graph Tabs {.tabset .tabset-pills}

```{r, results='asis'}
headers <- list('graph 1', 'graph 2', 'graph 3')

for (h in headers){
  cat("##", h, '<br>', '\n')
  cat('This is text for', h, '<br>')
  plot.new()
  plot(diffinv(rnorm(100)), type = 'o',  main = h)
  cat('\n', '<br>', '\n')
}
```
````

I want this to create a tab set with 3 tabs, each containing one of the graphs. Currently it's not working when I knit the file:

[image]

Is there any way to overcome this problem? Ideally I would like to get to a point where I can dynamically determine content that goes in an R markdown output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I add an extra newline at the end of each section, I get the desired results:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
headers <- list('graph 1', 'graph 2', 'graph 3')

for (h in headers){
  cat("##", h, '<br>', '\n')
  cat('This is text for', h, '<br>')
  plot.new()
  plot(diffinv(rnorm(100)), type = 'o',  main = h)
  cat('\n', '<br>', '\n\n')
}
```
````

Remember that Markdown often requires a full blank line between different elements.

Comment: Thank you - this solves the basic example I mentioned above. I should have mentioned that I am trying to make this with ggplot2 graphs.  It appears adding ggplot graphs in place of the base R graphs makes this solution not work. Though it may be out of scope, do you know how this could be fixed?

Comment: @Warner: based on related questions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43636120/1222578), I think the trick is to make sure that you `print()` the ggplot object at the appropriate point. You probably also want to get rid of `plot.new` when doing that.

Comment: I have a number_sections: yes in YAML header that makes the tabs numbered, is there a way to make them not numbered?