# Dynamic tabsets with containing JS, R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I recently asked a question about [dynamically creating tabsets containing graphs in R markdown.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725591/dynamically-control-number-of-tabsets-in-r-markdown)

There are different ways of plotting base R and ggplot graphs. However, it doesn't seem like either the approaches work for `DT` tables:

````
# DataTable Tabs {.tabset .tabset-pills}

```{r}
library(DT)

dt_list <- list(datatable(data.frame('x'=rnorm(100))),
                datatable(data.frame('y'=diffinv(rnorm(99)))),
                datatable(data.frame('z'=diff(rnorm(101)))))
names(dt_list) <- c('x','y','z')

```

```{r, results='asis'}
for(h in names(df)){
  cat("##", h, '<br>', '\n')
  cat('This is text for', h, '<br>', '\n\n')
  print(dt_list[[h]])
  cat('\n', '<br>', '\n\n')
}
```
````

[image: ggplot]

How would I go about rendering these tabs dynamically? I know `DT` tables are built on JS so I imagine the approach would also help with rendering a lot of other types of content dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where the problem lies. But there is already an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/67). 
A workaround is to render another table and remove it. Also take notice of the use of `tagList` within the loop. The datatable library seems to be loaded then and the tabbed datatables work:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---


# DataTable Tabs {.tabset .tabset-pills}

```{r}
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
# we simply select the table, look for the parent container 
# and remove it from the DOM
jsc <- 'function(settings, json) { $(this).parents(".datatables").remove(); }'
datatable(matrix(NA, 2, 2), options = list("initComplete" = JS(jsc)))
```


```{r}
dt_list <- list(datatable(data.frame('x'=1:10)),
                datatable(data.frame('y'=11:20)),
                datatable(data.frame('z'=21:30)))
names(dt_list) <- c('x','y','z')
```

```{r, results='asis'}
for(h in names(dt_list)){
  cat("##", h, '<br>', '\n')
  cat('This is text for', h, '<br>', '\n\n')
  print(tagList(dt_list[[h]]))
  cat('\n', '<br>', '\n\n')
}
```
````