# ggplot in Rmarkdown loop knit not working

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I have an .Rmd file that creates a random number of plots and stores them in a list(). I then run a chunk that creates RMarkdown dynamically based on how many are in the list. No matter what I try, I can not get each plot on the separate tabset when knitted. Most of the methods I have tried will plot all of the ggplots at the very last tab sequentially.

Here is reproduceable code that is similar to my issue:

````
---
title: ""
author: "Mark Gingrass"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '3'
  html_notebook:
    code_folding: hide
    theme: united
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: yes
keep_md: TRUE
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
my_data <- mtcars


p_list <- list()

p1 <- qplot(mpg, disp, data = my_data)
p2 <- qplot(mpg, disp, data = my_data)
p_list[[1]] <- p1
p_list[[2]] <- p2
```


### My Heading  {.tabset}
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
for (i in 1:length(p_list)){
  cat("####", i, " \n")
  print(p_list[[i]])
  cat(' \n\n')
}
```
````

plot.new() after the print statement makes this almost work; however, It will then print a blank plot after each of my plots. One workaround might be to use plot.new() then delete the plot? Everything works on the R Notebook just fine, it's when knitted I have the issues.

I've played around with dev.off() as well and got nowhere. I might not be using it properly.

Maybe there is an alternative solution altogether that I am not thinking of? Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, I'm getting one plot on each tab.

Comment: lolhithbb from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636120/r-how-do-you-embed-plots-into-a-tab-in-rmarkdown-in-a-procedural-fashion) : also has my same issue. I couldn't comment on that post and should have referenced it. 

Here is my r version info too:

arch           i386                        
os             mingw32                     
system         i386,  
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.0

Comment: Are you using ggplot 3.0.0? Run `packageVersion("ggplot2")`.

Comment: I can't reproduce when knitting to an HTML document (I get one plot after each header) but can if I switch to "previewing" an HTML Notebook.  Are you having problems with both output types?

Comment: If the problem is specific to a Notebook and I'm reading [this github issue conversation](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1795) correctly then such output might be expected.

Comment: @jaySf - looks like I am on version 2.2.1. I will update and let you know. Didn't even think of that.

Comment: It may be a good idea to update packages regularly since such issues might be solved in the meanwhile. You can update all of your packages in the IDE or using `update.packages()`. Also consider @aosmith 's comment since I only checked the HTML type.

Comment: @aosmith It gives me the same output for both HTML and Preview, all plots on last tab. I updated and still same issues. However, I am using R 3.5 and not R 3.5.1 still. Might not be able to update that at the moment with firewall but I will try.

Comment: @aosmith that post from github was it. Honestly, I didn't know there was a difference between the file created by using the "knit" button and actually using rmarkdown::render().  using rmarkdown::rendor("File.Rmd") solved my issue. Thank you to all.

Comment: Glad you found a fix!  Are you certain your knitr and/or RStudio versions are up-to-date?  While you can do a lot with render(), "Knit to HTML" worked fine for me but "Preview" did not (which I think is what that github issue was discussing).