# Adjust .tabset panel html output length R

Tags: html, css, r, layout, r-markdown

I've been trawling for a while to solve this one. Is there a way I can lengthen `.tabset` panels in an rmd HTML output, or ideally have them a dynamic length in the HTML output to stop plots getting squashed?

RePrEx:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
date: "2022-07-27"
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
gg0 <- list()

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, drat)) + geom_point()

gg0[[1]] <- p1/p1/p1/p1
gg0[[2]] <- p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1
gg0[[3]] <- p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1

headings <- c('hp','disp','drat')
```

#### Heading  {.tabset}
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
for (i in 1:length(gg0)) {
  cat("##### ",headings[i],"\n")
  print(gg0[[i]])
  cat('\n\n')
}
```
````

Example shamelessly borrowed and adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636120/how-to-embed-plots-into-a-tab-in-rmarkdown-in-a-procedural-fashion). Figures look quite small when knit, especially complex plots.

Thanks!

P.S. I'm not that familiar with CSS if it needs to be done that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RMarkdown we can control the size of plots using `fig.dim` `fig. width` or `fig.height` (see [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html)).

In your case setting `fig.height` to `10` yields good results:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
date: "2022-07-27"
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

gg0 <- list()

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, drat)) + geom_point()

gg0[[1]] <- p1/p1/p1/p1
gg0[[2]] <- p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1
gg0[[3]] <- p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1/p1

headings <- c('hp','disp','drat')
```

#### Heading  {.tabset}
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE, fig.height = 10}

for (i in 1:length(gg0)) {
  cat("##### ",headings[i],"\n")
  print(gg0[[i]])
  cat('\n\n')
}
```
````

Comment: oh dog, that was so simple... I was searching to find out how to adjust `.tabset` for ages. Thanks!